# Need Android ProtoBuf RPC Examples?

Tags: android, network-protocols, protocol-buffers

I'm learning about ProtoBufs and would like a good example of using it within Android and having the *.proto file(s) residing on a server.  I cant find any decent tutorials that are complete for RPC usage.

I would like class examples that show how to link to the data (ie: http:/a-site.com/my-file.proto) and then deserialize/inflate the data into a listView with linking. I don't need to serialize any data - just read & inflate it on the device.

PLZ note that I am currently learning about web-services; I do ready know how to create the *.proto files - I just need to learn the Android side. Otherwise I am sure it would have been easy for me to implement ProtoBufs already.

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Just to clarify a point, by convention, [`.proto`](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/proto.html) files are the _definition_ of your protocol buffer message format - they don't contain your actual data. These files are [compiled by `protoc` prior to deploy-time](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/javatutorial.html), so as far as I aware, pointing your android app at a url like http:/a-site.com/my-file.proto and then dynamically compiling the protocol buffer classes would be difficult - you tend to know your protocol buffer format in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The recently open-sourced Google Sky Map astronomy app for Android uses ProtoBuf to de-serialise data in `ProtobufAstronomicalSource`:

http://code.google.com/p/stardroid/source/browse/trunk/app/src/com/google/android/stardroid/source/proto/

One Android-relevant touch is that they're using a 'lite' version of the protobuf jar:

http://code.google.com/p/stardroid/source/browse/trunk/app/libs/protobuf-java-2.3.0-lite.jar

This needs you to add the [`LITE_RUNTIME`](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/proto.html#options) flag to your `.proto` files - this will generate Java proto classes that omit mobile-vm-unfriendly features like reflection.

Incidentally, Protocol Buffers itself doesn't exactly provide full-RPC (PB is just a way of encoding structured data), but as you probably know there are several third-party RPC implementations that sit on top:

http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns#RPC_Implementations